# Sort objects by length of self-referencing child collection in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a database table representing a hierarchical structure, meaning that it has a self-referencing foreign key. I want to sort my objects by the number of children they have.

The problem is that I can neither figure out how to do the appropriate self-join, nor how to ask for the count of the child collection within the original query. The result is that I am forced to resort to retrieving the children, getting the child collection length, and sorting the results in Python.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine("...")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class Variable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'variable'

    id          = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id   = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('variable.id'))
    parent = relationship('Variable', remote_side=[id], backref="children")

# Works fine
for v in session.query(Variable).all():
    print(len(v.children))

# Works fine
for v in session.query(Variable.id).all():
    print(v)

# AttributeError: type object 'Variable' has no attribute 'children'
for v in session.query(func.count(Variable.children)).all():
    print(v)

# AttributeError: type object 'Variable' has no attribute 'children'
for v in session.query(Variable.children).all():
    print(v)
```

It seems to think that it doesn't know about `children`, but only in certain contexts. As an experiment, I tried adding `children` explicitly:

```
children = relationship('Variable', backref="parent")
```

I got the following error:

```
Error creating backref 'parent' on relationship 'Variable.children': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Variable|variable'
```

The following solves the problem, but it's an atrocity: I'm pulling the entire collection just to count it, and I'm doing my sort client-side. How can I get SQLAlchemy to do this all database-side?

```
import operator
vars = {}
for v in db.session.query(Variable).all():
    vars[v.id] = len(v.children)

sorted_vars = sorted(vars.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: Since it seems you want immediate children only, can't you just group by parent_id and order by count?

Comment: I like the idea. The problem is that then I lose all the leaf nodes (which don't have any children, and thus don't produce groups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fetch the number of immediate children would be to just group by `parent_id` and count, but as you've noted you'd lose leaf nodes that have no children. To remedy this you could create a subquery of the counts and join back against `Variable`, coalescing NULL values to 0. On the other hand a subquery is unnecessary in that case:

```
child = aliased(Variable)
session.query(Variable,
              func.count(child.id).label('child_count')).\
    outerjoin(child, Variable.children).\
    group_by(Variable.id).\
    order_by(literal_column('child_count')).\
    all()
```

Since the primary key is guaranteed to be not NULL the count will produce NULL values only for left with no matching right, or no children. If you're not interested in the actual count, move it entirely in the ORDER BY clause.